# Autosys owner attribute - How to avoid hardcoding the value?

Tags: autosys

I have lower (UAT) and upper (PROD) environments, where Autosys jobs are run into UAT first, tested and then promoted to PROD.

The main differences between the environments, from an autosys job perspective, are the **machine** and **owner** attributes.

Ideally, I would like to promote the *exact same job definition* from UAT to PRDD. Currently I don't because of the two attributes that differ; machine and owner.

For the machine attribute, I can use a virtual machine definition, so no issue there.

Is there a similar approach that I can use to abstract the owner values?

I've had no luck with some extensive googling.